# matSort not working with multiple mat-tables

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I have a page with 2 mat-tables populated from 2 data sources. The sorting isn't working for me. Please advise. [Here is the stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nbx7vk)

TS File

```
export class TableSortingExample implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  displayedColumns2: string[] = ['position2', 'name2', 'weight2'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);
  dataSource2 = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA2);

   @ViewChildren(MatSort)
  sort = new QueryList<MatSort>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort.toArray()[0];
    this.dataSource2.sort = this.sort.toArray()[1];
  }
}
```

I couldn't put the html file here, stackoverflow said too much code in question. Please go over to the stackblitz to see the html.

Comment: Do u have the tables inside mat-tab? If yes, the datasource for table 2 will not be initialized unless you click on the tab.

Comment: No, I don't use mat-tab. The datasource is initilized and the data can be seen in both the tables. Just the matSort alone is not working in either of them.

Comment: Check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53954062/paginator-not-working-on-multiple-table-with-angular-material-table/53955557#53955557

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Thanks! I've updated my stackblitx with this approach. First table is sorting fine now, but not the second table. Could you please take a look ?

Comment: @jijo Ok will check

Comment: @jijo Check the updated answer

Comment: Check the updated answer and let me know it works or not!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale It did work on stackblitz, but unfortunately not in my code, which is a bit different and have more tables. Will keep looking.

Comment: @jijo Np problem. You can also the current code which is not working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is related to column names and keys of an object that you are using for iteration:

For example:

`DataSource` for the second table

```
const ELEMENT_DATA2: any[] = [
  { position: 11, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079 },
  { position: 12, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026 },
  { position: 13, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941 },
  { position: 14, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122 }
];
```

Column names for the second table is:

```
displayedColumns2: string[] = ['position2', 'name2', 'weight2'];
```

which actually mismatch from above object key, so just change the JSON Object which matches the `keys` same as `displayedColumns2` so the sort function will know the columns names on which it has to sort.

Like:

```
const ELEMENT_DATA2: any[] = [
  { position2: 11, name2: 'Hydrogen', weight2: 1.0079 },
  { position2: 12, name2: 'Helium', weight2: 4.0026 },
  { position2: 13, name2: 'Lithium', weight2: 6.941 },
  { position2: 14, name2: 'Beryllium', weight2: 9.0122 }
];
```

[`StackBlitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nbx7vk-opl6f3)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it should work for the first table and second at once. But you still have to make small changes to make sorting tables works separated for each table alone.

I have tested it on your code on Stackblitz, and it works.

I commented out the stuff you have to change/remove. And don't forget to import `ViewChild` from `@angular/core`

I'am not sure if you do need it also in `ngAfterViewInit`.
Hope it helps you and put you in the right direction.

```
export class TableSortingExample implements OnInit {
    displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
    displayedColumns2: string[] = ['position2', 'name2', 'weight2'];
    dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);
    dataSource2 = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA2);

    // @ViewChildren(MatSort)
    // sort = new QueryList<MatSort>();
    @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
    numberOfMatSort = 0;
    ngOnInit() {
      // this.dataSource.sort = this.sort.toArray()[0];
      // this.dataSource2.sort = this.sort.toArray()[1];
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
       console.log(this.sort);
       // this.sort.forEach(m => console.log(m));

      // setTimeout(() => this.numberOfMatSort = this.sort.length, 0);
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }
 }
```

Comment: I need them to be sorted separately, not at once. This approach didn't work in that case.

Comment: As I said, modify, enhance the code, and create an initialization with sort for each table. The direction you were going was wrong. I posted the first step, where you should go.